# How to use a Network adapter only for a specific Connection on Win7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, connection, internet-connection, network-adapter

I've got several network adapter in my PC (from LAN, WLAN, VPN etc...) and what I want to accomplish is that some specific adresses use the VPN adapter, while all others use eiter LAN or WLAN. 
(So for example http://win-server/ is using VPN, while www.google still uses LAN connection.)

I've want to solve this with the Windows settings and not the VPN settings to make sure I can do it with every VPN-Provider.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add it to the routing table...

```
C:\> route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1 metric 1 if 2
                                ^ netmask                   interface ^
C:\> route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.0.0.1 metric 2 if 1
               ^ destination           ^gateway        ^ metric
```

etc etc...

Comment: that is what I will write for the VPN, I think. But how to tell Windows to use LAN/WLAN for all other Routes?

Comment: you add a default route

Comment: I don't think that's what the poster is asking about. Windows (and most any OS) will automatically set up correct routing tables when you have multiple interfaces. I think he means being able to direct certain web traffic through interface "X" while having other traffic go through interface "Y". You could probably do it through static routes, routing an IP address of a site through the gateway on the wanted interface but it would be a complex setup and you'd have to navigate pages by IP seeing how most major sites resolve to multiple IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Many VPN providers prevent this, unless you enable what is called "Split Tunneling".  Cisco is a common VPN provider that does this.  Unless the admin of your VPN concentrator has explicitly allowed split tunneling, and defined which ip subnets should use the VPN, then all traffic will flow through the VPN.

Comment: Well, I don't want to to this via VPN Settings, but via Windows beacuse of the resulting universality

Comment: This is absolutely correct - Split Tunnelling needs to be in place, and admin needs to allow this on the VPN gateway. What you are referring to, however, is Inverse Split Tunnelling, where all datagrams enter the tunnel by default, except those destination IPs explicitly allowed by VPN gateway to bypass the gateway and go through a direct rout to the net provided by the gateway. This keeps control of network gateways to a centralized policy device such as the VPN terminator, while keeping overheads minimal.